# Conflict between preceding-sibling and xsl:sort

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have got something like this:

```
  <Root>
    <res>
      <Title> XXXXXXX </Title>
      <A xlink:href='#a1111'/>
      <A xlink:href='#a5000'/>
      <A xlink:href='#a3333'/>
      <A xlink:href='#a1000'/>
    </res>
    <res>
      <Title> YYYYYYY </Title>
      <A xlink:href='#a8888'/>
      <A xlink:href='#a1000'/>
    </res>
    <def-list>
         <Criteria xml:id="a1111">
             <code> CodeX </code>
             Content A
         </Criteria>
         <Treatment xml:id="a5000">
             <code> CodeT </code>
               Content B
         </Treatment>
         <Population xml:id="a3333">
             <code> CodeY </code>
               Content C
         </Population>
         <Criteria xml:id="a1000">
             <code> CodeZ </code>
               Content D
         </Criteria>
         <Population xml:id="a8888">
             <code> CodeE </code>
               Content F
         </Population>
    </def-list>
  </Root>
```

Notice that each element under def-list can be used by more than one res like “a1000” which has been used by both res

And in my xslt I have:

```
 <xsl:key name='defination' match='/Root/def-list/*' use='concat("#", @xml:id)'/>

<xsl:template match="/" >
<xsl:apply-templates select='/Root/res' />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="res" >
     <xsl:apply-templates select='A'>
          <xsl:sort select="local-name(key('mykeys', @xlink:href))"  order="ascending"  />
          <xsl:sort select='key("mykeys", @xlink:href)/code'/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="A">

    <xsl:variable name='ref' select ='@xlink:href' />

    <xsl:variable name='sibling' select='./preceding-sibling::*[1][self::A]' />
        <xsl:variable name='hasprecedingsibling'>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test='name(key("'mykeys'", $ref)) = name(key("'mykeys'", $sibling/@xlink:href))'>
                <xsl:value-of select="'true'" />
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>


    <xsl:variable name='title'>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test='$hasprecedingsibling != ""'>
                 <xsl:value-of select="'AND '"/>
            </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select='concat(local-name(), " :")' />
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:apply-templates mode="exclude-code"/>

 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="code"  mode="exclude-code" >
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Both XML and XSLT have been simplified)

The output should be:

```
 Criteria:

      Content A
 And

      Content D

 Population:

      Content C

 Treatment:

      Content B
```

Notice that the format and the ordering and the titles should be as above.

I have to use XSLT 1.0 and I am also using .NET processor (XslCompiledTransform)

The issue is that preceding-sibling works with the original order while I have changed the order by using sort.

I need both sort elements but I don’t how I can apply preceding-sibling to the new order not to the original one. Any thought?

Comment: Obviously, you will need to use some other method to achieve your goal. However, it's not clear what that goal is. Why don't you provide an example of the original, unsorted input, explain how to sort it and  what to look for in the result (and why). -- Possible hint: if you know *how* the elements were sorted, then you also know which one precedes the other in the sorted tree.

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0? Or if you're stuck on 1.0 what processor are you using?

Comment: @IanRoberts, I have to use XSLT 1.0 and I am also using .NET processor (XslCompiledTransform)

Answer (score 0):

> I have got something like this:

No, you can't have "something like this" because "this" uses undefined namespace prefixes. Also your second sort makes no sense , because there is no `Code' element on the other side of the key. And your first sort needs to be *ascending*, not *descending* to get the result you indicate.

Anyway, this can (and IMHO should) be perceived as a grouping issue. So, if we strip your input to something like this:

```
<Root>
    <res>
      <A href='#a1111'  Code='CodeX' />
      <A href='#a5000'  Code='CodeT' />
      <A href='#a3333'  Code='CodeY' />
      <A href='#a1000'  Code='CodeZ' />
    </res>
    <def-list>
         <Criteria id="a1111">
               Content A
         </Criteria>
         <Treatment id="a5000">
               Content B
         </Treatment>
         <Population id="a3333">
               Content C
         </Population>
         <Criteria id="a1000">
               Content D
         </Criteria>
    </def-list>
  </Root>
```

and apply the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:key name="defById" match="def-list/*" use="concat('#', @id)" />
<xsl:key name="defByName" match="def-list/*" use="local-name()" />

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:for-each select="Root/res/A">
<xsl:sort select="local-name(key('defById', @href))" order="ascending"/>
<xsl:sort select="Code"/>

    <xsl:variable name="name" select="local-name(key('defById', @href))" />

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@href = concat('#', key('defByName', $name)[1]/@id) ">
            <xsl:value-of select="$name" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text >AND</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

    <xsl:text >:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="key('defById', @href)" />

</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

we will get this output:

```
Criteria:
               Content A
         AND:
               Content D
         Population:
               Content C
         Treatment:
               Content B
```

Apply normalize-space() and add more text elements to format this the way you want.

Comment: sorry It’s not what I want